# stdout and stderr - side-by-side preview

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, tmux, gnu-screen

I would like to split stdout and stderr and be able to see them side-by-side during program execution.

All solutions I knows require redirection of one or both streams to file.

My solutions:

1. Redirect stdout and stderr to different files, and then `tail -f` both files in separate terminal windows or inside tmux/screen. This requires 3 terminals - 1 for command invocation, and two for preview.
2. Redirect only stderr to files, and the `taif -f` the file in separate terminal. This requires 2 terminals - 1 for command invocation and stdout, and one for stderr preview.

Both solutions are inconvenient, because you have to run multiple commands  and switch between terminals.

Are there any better solutions for this problem? Is there a way to avoid redirection to file?

Comment: See [here](http://sharats.me/the-ever-useful-and-neat-subprocess-module.html), searching for "watching both stdout and stderr" for a possible beginning of an idea. Basically it would be a python wrapper running your script and displaying output as you program it. Definitely not as simple as a ready-made utility...

Comment: Maybe [screen ... exec](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) might be usable? I've never used it, but seems possibly promising.

Comment: @PeterBowers, I'm looking for kind of wrapper to avoid redirection to files. I had no luck with executing screen as a simple onliner or script, and I don't want to create separate screen configuration file for this purpose.

Comment: [Here's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/scrolledtext.html) a way to do text scrolling in python.

Comment: [Here's](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/tk/ch06_01.htm) something in perl, if that's your platform of choice.  Or, better yet, [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/tk/ch15_04.htm) where it references and gives code for at least half of the problem you are solving.

Comment: [And another](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tk::Stderr) specifically for handling stderr in perl/tk. Since it automatically puts it in a separate window this might solve the problem?

Answer (score 7):

so because OP asked specifically for side by side, one option: tmux!
(tmux is a little heavy but it does split panes pretty well I guess so example:)

1. `$ tmux`
2. Split your panes:
3. left-right:

   <kbd>^b</kbd> + <kbd>%</kbd>
   (<kbd>^b</kbd> means ctrl+b)
4. top-bottom:

   <kbd>^b</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd>
5. Focus your error pane:

   <kbd>^b</kbd> + <kbd>↑↓→←</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>
6. `$ tty`, copy your error pane's device file
7. Re Focus your output pane:

   <kbd>^b</kbd> + <kbd>↑↓→←</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>
8. `$ your-command 2>/dev/pts/N`

   where `/dev/pts/N` is the value you coped from the other pane

Neat! :camera-flash:

Comment: Made my day! <3

Comment: and if you want the `less` experience you can use a named pipe: `$ mkfifo <name>` `$ less -f <name>` `$ command 2> <name>`

Comment: ps, to swap panes the default hostkey is `^b` and any arrowkey, close your shell to close a pane.

Answer (score 5):

If it is the file creation you want to avoid, you can do this...

Start a new Terminal, and in there, type `tty` to find that terminal's device special file, e.g `/dev/ttys002`

Then in your original Terminal, run your command like this:

```
yourProgram 2> /dev/ttys002
```

I used this as a test program:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..30}; do
   echo hi
   echo hi to stderr >&2
done
```

Comment: Often you have to set permissions on the remote terminal b4 you can output to it. Not that I ever did this to classmates or work colleagues to befuddle them or anything... :-)

Comment: @PeterBowers That's a relief as I never rlogined to a friend's Solaris box and played any audio files at full volume either;-)